# Play framework routing with case insensitive request arguments

Tags: java, playframework, routes, playframework-2.0

I've got a play framework routes file like this:

```
GET     /files/*path     controllers.Files.getListOfFiles(fileslimit: Int ?= 10)
```

which works perfectly fine for requests like this:

```
.../path/to/folder?fileslimit=5
```

But I would like to make **request parameter** limitoffiles case insensitive, so that all requests like these would give similar correct result:

```
.../path/to/folder?fileslimit=5
.../path/to/folder?filesLimit=5
.../path/to/folder?FilesLimit=5
.../path/to/folder?FILESLIMIT=5
```

How can I achieve this?